# Default String value in number picker

Tags: android

i m using a number picker to show string values. in case when no value get from adapter then default value is shown "0". i want my number picker to be String default value when adapter not set any value..

```
<NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/sub_category"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this--

```
StringFormatter implements Formatter {
public String toString(int value) {
    switch(value) {
        case 0:
            return "String1";
        case 1:
            return "String2";
    }
    return "Unknown";
}
}
```

`picker.setFormatter(new StringFormatter());
}`

Comment: `numberPicker = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.number_picker);
        //NumberPicker picker = new NumberPicker(this);
        numberPicker.setMinValue(0);
        numberPicker.setMaxValue(2);
        numberPicker.setDisplayedValues( new String[] { "Belgium", "France", "United Kingdom" } );`

Comment: try something like this

Comment: you have to set some value in your activity if the adapter returns 0